# SQL Server 2005: converting varchar to nvarchar issue

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar

I have table with two `varchar` columns `first_name` and `last_name`.

Now I need to convert these columns to `nvarchar` in order to support UTF-8.

I choose `nvarchar` datatype in SSMS for these columns and when I try to enter some UTF-8 data, my symbols converts to question marks. For example, if I input `йцукен` (Ukrainian) it will be converted to `??????`.

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/761036/806549?

Comment: SQL Server nvarchar is UTF-16. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to insert `nvarchar` literals into the database table, you **must** use the `N'..'` prefix.

So use

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(First_Name)
VALUES(N'йцукен')
```

so that this string will be treated as a **unicode** string

If you're not using the `N'..'` notation, you're really inserting a **non-unicode** string literal - and this will cause these conversions to `?`

Comment: Every little helps. This is something we forget everyday... +1

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case. It display question marks even when I try to update table with 'N' character. For example, UPDATE mytable
SET first_name=N'йцукен'
WHERE id='10' will save question marks as before. In spite of this, when I create new table with nvarchar columns, everything works fine.