# SQL Server displays ??? instead of Unicode characters

Tags: sql-server-2008, unicode, character-encoding, windows-8.1

I run SQL Server 2008 Express on my Windows 8.1. After inserting some Unicode characters in Database, characters are not displayed properly (the data has no problem just displayed improperly). Manually inserting the values using 'Management Studio' will lead to the same result.
I typed information in Persian Language and installed persial Language pack for Windows 8.1 however this does not fixed anything.
[image]

Am I missed something in SQL Server options? The same configuration on windows 7 have no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check if your field is UNICODE (nchar or nvarchar).
2. Check collation for your database.
3. Make sure your UNICODE literals have N prefix.

UPDATE: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761036/why-is-sql-server-storing-question-mark-characters-instead-of-japanese-character), possible duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

Changing type of fields from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR fixes the problem but it does not recover data stored in bad format.