# Unable to insert unicode characters through freetds unixODBC in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode, freetds, unixodbc

I have a c++ application built on RHEL 5 that connects to MS SQL 2008 through freeTDS and unixODBC situated on a windows machine.

This is the query the application sends to the database.

`INSERT INTO mytable (SAMPLE) VALUES(N'乕乭乺丕')`

`Um@D@Iz` is actually inserted into the database when the above query is invoked.

Following are the configurations which I am using -

```
== freetds.conf ==
[myserver.mydomain.com]
client charset = UTF-16
debug flags = 0xffff
dump file = /tmp/dump.log
dump file append = yes
host = 127.0.01
port = 1433
tds version = 7.3

== odbcinst.ini ==
[FreeTDS Driver]
Description     = FreeTDS
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0

== odbc.ini ==
[mydsn]
Description     = MS SQL connection to 'mydb' database
Driver          = FreeTDS Driver
Servername      = myserver.mydomain.com
Port            = 1433
TDS_Version     = 7.3
Database        = mydb
UserName        = sa
Password        = mypassword
Trace           = Yes
TraceFile       = /tmp/odbc.log
ForceTrace      = Yes
```

I can directly insert the data into the database through

`INSERT INTO mytable (SAMPLE) VALUES(N'乕乭乺丕')` but not through freeTDS and unixODBC

Please find the code which i am using below:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
#endif

#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>

#include "unicode/ustdio.h"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SQLHSTMT hSQLStatement = 0;
  SQLHENV hSQLEnvironment = 0;
  SQLHDBC hSQLODBC = 0;

  SQLRETURN sqlRet = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hSQLEnvironment);

  if(SQL_SUCCEEDED(sqlRet))
  {
    sqlRet = SQLSetEnvAttr(hSQLEnvironment, 
                           SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
                           (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 
                           0);

    if(SQL_SUCCEEDED(sqlRet))
    {
        sqlRet = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, 
                                hSQLEnvironment, 
                                &hSQLODBC);
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Error in SQLAllocHandle for SQL_HANDLE_DBC" << endl;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Error in SQLAllocHandle for SQL_HANDLE_ENV" << endl;
  }

  UnicodeString DSNName = "mydsn";
  UnicodeString UserName = "sa";
  UnicodeString Password = "mypassword";

  UnicodeString Value = "";

  UChar32 character = 20053;
  Value.append(character);

  character = 20077;
  Value.append(character);

  character = 131140;
  Value.append(character);

  character = 131145;
  Value.append(character);

  character = 20090;
  Value.append(character);

  character = 19989;
  Value.append(character);

  UnicodeString SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO mytable (sample) VALUES(N";
  SQLStatement.append("'");
  SQLStatement.append(Value);
  SQLStatement.append("'");
  SQLStatement.append(")");

  if(0 != hSQLODBC)
  {
    SQLRETURN sqlRet = SQLConnectW(hSQLODBC, 
                                   (SQLWCHAR*)DSNName.getTerminatedBuffer(),
                                   SQL_NTS, 
                                   (SQLWCHAR*)UserName.getTerminatedBuffer(),
                                   SQL_NTS,
                                   (SQLWCHAR*)Password.getTerminatedBuffer(),
                                   SQL_NTS);

    if(SQL_SUCCEEDED(sqlRet))
    {
      cout << "Connection to database successful" << endl;

      SQLRETURN sqlRet = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, 
                                        hSQLODBC, 
                                        &hSQLStatement);

      if(SQL_SUCCEEDED(sqlRet))
      {
        sqlRet = SQLExecDirectW(hSQLStatement, 
                                (SQLWCHAR*)SQLStatement.getTerminatedBuffer(), 
                                SQL_NTS);

        if(SQL_SUCCEEDED(sqlRet))
        {
          cout << "Query Execution successful" << endl;
        }
        else
          cout << "Query Execution failed" << endl;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Connection to database failed" << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

EDIT 1: Added sample code

EDIT 2: Updated as per Oliver's suggestion

Comment: data type of `SAMPLE` column must be `NVARCHAR`

Comment: yes the datatype is `NVARCHAR`

Comment: What version of FreeTDS are you using? 0.95, 0.91? TDS Version 7.3 is only supported in FreeTDS 0.95. I believe 0.91 ships with RHEL 6, but I'm not sure with RHEL 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is sql server storing question mark characters instead of Japanese characters in NVarchar fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761036/why-is-sql-server-storing-question-mark-characters-instead-of-japanese-character)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses UTF-16 for `NVARCHAR`. From the information in your question it looks like you have strings in UTF-8. First convert the insert statement to UTF-16 before sending it to SQL Server.

---

Update: I'm seeing you added the code sample. I see you appending [`UChar32`](https://ssl.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/umachine_8h.html#a09fff5c3b5a5b015324dc3ec3cf92809) values to the `UnicodeString` instance. Those are 4 bytes wide. AFAICT you need to [`append`](https://ssl.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#ab648b1668a7e12d76c6eebc7240e7f53) [`UChar`](https://ssl.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/umachine_8h.html#a6bb9fad572d65b305324ef288165e2ac) values (2 bytes wide).

Comment: The same query when invoked through c++ application built on windows using `SQL Server Native Client 10.0` odbc driver is successfully inserted in the database. I am not sure what FreeTDS might be doing here.

Comment: @D3XT3R Looking at what is actually inserted, this smells of narrowing to single bytes rather than the double bytes in a UTF-16 string. Just as a test convert the string to a byte array, and insert the string as `INSERT INTO mytable(sample)VALUES(CAST(0x<byte pattern> AS NVARCHAR(4000))` where byte pattern is the series of bytes in HEX form for the string in **UTF-16**.

Comment: @D3XT3R You should really consider adding an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, ie the code to reproduce the problem you have. Perhaps the problem is in your code rather than in the FreeDTS driver. Are you using a string type that is in UTF-16?

Comment: @D3XT3R That would be UTF-16 LE (Little Endian) by the way.

Comment: @D3XT3R I'm coming from a JAVA/SQL-Server background... I'm just going off mostly from what I know about SQL-Server and the symptoms you describe in your question. The MVCE is really needed if you want experts in C++/FreeDTS to be able to tell anything about what you might be doing wrong at that level.

Comment: @D3XT3R No thanks. You have to have the code inside your question, by providing a minimal/complete/verifiable/example. That's how SO works, questions should have the information in the question, not an offsite resource.

Comment: @D3XT3R Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The ICU UnicodeString Documentation here (https://ssl.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#details) says "In ICU, a Unicode string consists of 16-bit Unicode code units." Since you use `SQLStatement.getTerminatedBuffer()` to get at that data, I read that as the data being in UTF-16 when you grab it and push it into SQLExecDirectW().

On the other hand you specify `client charset = UTF-8` in your FreeTDS config. Since it works with the Native Client, I'd try to change the charset for FreeTDS Client to UTF-16.

Comment: updated my charset to UTF-16, the same issue persists.