# Not able to replace special character in nvarchar string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to split a string which is `nvarchar(max)`
if I pass the string like

```
@String_xyz = 'abc@def#ghi$jkl'
```

Then I am able to replace the special character but my character comes in a unreadable format like `?????`

If I send my string like this way

```
@String_xyz = N'abc@def#ghi$jkl'
```

Then I am not able to replace any special character

Let say

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)
SET @string = 'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது'
SET @string = replace(@string,'##',' ') -- This work perfect
```

if

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)
SET @string = N'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது'
SET @string = replace(@string,'##',' ') -- This will not work
```

Please let me know any possible solution 
`where abc-def-ghi-jkl are multilanguage character`

Collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: This sound like an encoding problem.  What encoding is your SQL Server using?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Please give details, show your code... What characters are there in your string and how do you want to replace them And what does *split a string* mean exactly?

Comment: @Shnugo updated my question

Comment: `@string` is nvarchar

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/761036/5089204 What language is this?

Comment: I can insert the unicode data into fields I need to replace the special characters

Comment: The second sample works fine for me (if you put a `SET ` before the second line). SQL Server 2012. Just on a hunch: Have you tried using `REPLACE(@string, N'##',N' ')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is **UNICODE**

You have to make sure, that you use unicode **in all places**

Literal strings must be started with an `N` **everywhere**

Try this

```
--This will come out with question marks
SELECT 'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது';
--And this is the correct output
SELECT N'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது';

--Here I replace one of the characters with a "%"
SELECT REPLACE(N'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது',N'கி',N'%')
```

This works fine here...

#### UPDATE

Cannot verify this anymore, but it might be, that the output was wrong at the first try. I tried around with several collations. With this I got the wanted

```
SELECT N'YourString' COLLATE Indic_General_90_BIN;
```

After having used this, it was OK. So - but this is just guessing - it might be, that SQL Server had to *learn* this first...

Answer (score 0):

If your code is like

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) = N'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்
SET @string = replace(@string,'##',' ')
```

results as

```
என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது
```

if

```
DECLARE @string1 nvarchar(max) = 'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது'
SET @string1 = replace(@string1,'##',' ')
```

then

```
???$?????@PIN@?????? ???$?????@KUL@??????
```

if

```
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max) = 'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது'
SET @string2 = replace(@string2,'##',' ')
```

then

```
???$?????@PIN@?????? ???$?????@KUL@??????
```

if

```
DECLARE @string3 varchar(max) = N'என்$பெயர்@PIN@ஆகிறது##என்$பெயர்@KUL@ஆகிறது'
SET @string3 = replace(@string3,'##',' ')
```

then

```
???$?????@PIN@?????? ???$?????@KUL@??????
```

if you declares string as nvarchar you have to give N' before the string otherwise unicodes will not work.