# How to import a CSV with Japanese (utf-8) using TablePlus?

Tags: sql-server, table-plus

I'm using TablePlus import tool to import CSV to my local SQL Server DB.
The files are big enough to avoid using Excel spreadsheet (~70 Mb), and when opening the tool it appears to support Japanese alphabet:

[image]

I set all columns to be varchar(max), with the Name column as nvarchar(max).
Sadly, when querying the table, the Japanese data is being retrieved as question marks.

[image]

In referred to questions on Stackoverflow [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761036/why-is-sql-server-storing-question-mark-characters-instead-of-japanese-character), that suggested inserting using N prefix. It works when running a sample query (e.g. `SELECT 'ケンガンアシュラ', N'ケンガンアシュラ'` ). Sadly, it appears like the built-in tool doesn't do it when inserting, hence the question mark. With hundreds of thousands of records, I cannot insert manually or generate a script. I also made sure the editor encoding is set to UTF, and it is.

[image]

Lastly, I tried querying using collation, but to no avail:

[image]

To conclude, it seems like I'm missing a hotfix. Would love a walk-around. Thanks!!

Comment: What data type in Name column. Try change to Nvarchar

Comment: @KreminT , it is Nvarchar..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used DBeaver to upload the CSVs. Works fine. Thanks y'all!